# How to refresh a Button Property inside a ListBox

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, listbox

I have 2 List Boxes on different pages with a Button like this:

```
<ListBox x:Name="mainlist" >
      <Button x:Name="but1" />
</ListBox>
```

and second

```
<ListBox x:Name="secondlist" >
    <Button x:Name="but2" Tag="but1" Click = "button_click" />
</ListBox>
```

On Application Initialization I set the Opacity of but 1 to 0 :

```
 public Main()
 {
       InitializeComponent();
       but1.Opacity = 0;
 }
```

and I want that when I press but2 to set Opacity to 100 for but1:

```
private void button_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var name = (sender as Button).Tag.ToString();
    object item = mainlist.FindName(name);
    if (item is Button)
    {
        (item as Button).Opacity = 100;
    }
}
```

But this does not update the but1 opacity. So the question is how to force update?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to achieve with your code, but if I've understood you properly - you want to make first button visible this way, then your code is working properly. The problem is that both your buttons doesn't have `Content` and one is over the other. So you make it Visible, but under the `but2`. Try to modify your XAML like this and run your procedure:

```
<StackPanel>
    <ListBox x:Name="mainlist" >
        <Button x:Name="but1" Content="First"/>
    </ListBox>
    <ListBox x:Name="secondlist" >
        <Button x:Name="but2" Tag="but1" Click="button_click" Content="Second"/>
    </ListBox>
</StackPanel>
```

On the other hand - `Opacity` has values from 0 to 1, so you may use `1` instead of `100`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your button click event as below.

```
private void button_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var name = (sender as Button).Tag.ToString();
    foreach (var item in mainlist.Items)
    {
        //if you know the button by name do this
        if(item is Button && ((Button)item).Name == "but1")
        {
            (item as Button).Opacity = 1d;
        }

        //set all the buttons opacity with 1 if tag is "some value" do this
        if(item is Button && ((Button)item).Tag== "Mark")
        {
            (item as Button).Opacity = 1d;
        }

        //set if you want to set all buttons opacity in the list do this
        if(item is Button)
        {
            (item as Button).Opacity = 1d;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem is that I have a lot of buttons... here I presented an example. And this is not a solution